# How to add UISegmetedControl to the center of a UINavigation?

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I know how to do this:

```
UIBarButtonItem * segmentBarItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: segmentedControl] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
```

How do I add it to the center though, where the title would be?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentBarItem;
```